# MySQL Server shuts down randomly with "[Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Normal shutdown" and no errors

Tags: mysql, memory, innodb, shutdown

I have been running some scripts to upload data to my database overnight and randomly, the MySQL server shuts down (NOTE: that these shutdowns have occurred when not running scripts, too). There are no errors in the ".err" file. It just starts a normal shutdown and displays

> "[Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Normal shutdown."

These occurrences have started to happen more and more frequently. I have done some research on it, and I think it could potentially have something to do with available memory, but this is just speculation. Here is the output of "/proc/meminfo"

> Blockquote
>   MemTotal:        3922212 kB
>   MemFree:          271928 kB
>   Buffers:          269676 kB
>   Cached:          1264516 kB
>   SwapCached:        27720 kB
>   Active:          1939724 kB
>   Inactive:        1542888 kB
>   Active(anon):    1380536 kB
>   Inactive(anon):   568308 kB
>   Active(file):     559188 kB
>   Inactive(file):   974580 kB
>   Unevictable:           0 kB
>   Mlocked:               0 kB
>   SwapTotal:       4194300 kB
>   SwapFree:        4118012 kB
>   Dirty:               132 kB
>   Writeback:             0 kB
>   AnonPages:       1934588 kB
>   Mapped:            30780 kB
>   Shmem:               384 kB
>   Slab:             103396 kB
>   SReclaimable:      73956 kB
>   SUnreclaim:        29440 kB
>   KernelStack:        5360 kB
>   PageTables:        11848 kB
>   NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
>   Bounce:                0 kB
>   WritebackTmp:          0 kB
>   CommitLimit:     6155404 kB
>   Committed_AS:    4359756 kB
>   VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
>   VmallocUsed:       23388 kB
>   VmallocChunk:   34359617408 kB
>   HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
>   AnonHugePages:         0 kB
>   HugePages_Total:       0
>   HugePages_Free:        0
>   HugePages_Rsvd:        0
>   HugePages_Surp:        0
>   Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
>   DirectMap4k:        8180 kB
>   DirectMap2M:     4186112 kB

As you can imagine, this has become quite an annoyance. If anyone has an idea of what might be causing this or where to look to find more information, please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this in some Cloud?  What time do they do maintenance?  Check the Uptime now -- `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Uptime';`  (It's in seconds; 86400/day.)

Answer (score 0):

It's not the memory issue. Note `Normal shutdown`, it happens in two cases:

1. mysqladmin shut
2. mysqld receives SIGTERM

I'm almost certain something tries to shutdown MySQL gracefully. It may be RPM/deb post-installation script. Not sure about recent versions, but in past the postinst scripts restarted mysqld.